# Django - getting Error Reverse for 'book' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['<int:flight_id/book\\Z']

Tags: python, html, sql, django, django-models

I am learning the Django framework. Today I was trying to retrieve a URL in HTML template by using

`<form action="{% url 'book' flight.id %}" method="post">`

Also, I've got a function book. Here is the code:

```
def book(request,flight_id):
   if request.method=="POST":
        flight=Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
        passenger=Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
        passenger.flights.add(flight)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight",args=(flight.id,)))
```

And this is the urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>",views.flight,name="flight"),
    path("<int:flight_id/book",views.book,name="book")
]
```

But I don't know why it is showing an error:

> NoReverseMatch at /1
> Reverse for 'book' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['<int:flight_id/book\Z']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book url pattern is not correct, there is a minor error. You are missing a clossing `>` here `path("<int:flight_id/book",views.book,name="book")`. It should look like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>",views.flight,name="flight"),
    path("<int:flight_id>/book",views.book,name="book")
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just didn't see it.